# Long-running thread work killed by PerformWaitCallback()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, service, threadpool

I got service that "hosts" another assemblies and let them processing tasks. So here is code excerpt:

```
public void Start()
{
    Log.Instance.Info("Trying runtime to start");
    // Loading all modules
    _workerLoader = new WorkerLoader();
    Log.Instance.Info("Trying to load workers");
    _workerLoader.CreateInstances();
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    foreach (var worker in _workerLoader.Modules)
    {
        Log.Instance.Info("Adding {0} to global scope", worker.Id);
        var currentWorker = worker;
        _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BaseWork(currentWorker, _tokenSource.Token), _tokenSource.Token));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    Log.Instance.Info("Runtime started");
}

private void BaseWork(IWorker worker, CancellationToken token)
{
    using (worker)
    {
        worker.WorkerStopped += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
            var strFrames = "";
            if (stackFrames != null)
            {
                strFrames =
                    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, stackFrames.Select(
                        x =>
                            String.Format("{0} {1} ({2}:{3})", x.GetMethod(), x.GetFileName(), x.GetFileLineNumber(), x.GetFileColumnNumber())));
            }

            Log.Instance.Info("[{0}] Worker stopped. ({1})", worker.Id, strFrames);
        };
        worker.TaskStarted += (sender, info) => Log.Instance.Info("[{0}] Started: {1}", ((IWorker)sender).Id, info.id);
        worker.TaskFinished += (sender, info) => Log.Instance.Info("[{0}] Finished: {1}", ((IWorker)sender).Id, info.id);
        worker.ErrorOccurred += (sender, exception) => Log.Instance.Error("[{0}] Error: {1}", ((IWorker)sender).Id, exception);
        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            worker.ProcessOnce();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `worker.ProcessOnce()` worker makes all necessary operations like connecting to remote website, fetching data from DB, writing to DB, etc. There is only one worker at the moment.

After some not so tricky explanations going down to issue.

The issue is that after some time of normal working, worker get stopped, emits regarding entry to log file. It occurs randomly. I catch the stack trace, injecting some code you can see in "worker stopped" event handler and here you go:

```
Worker stopped. (Void <BaseWork>b__3(System.Object, System.EventArgs)  (0:0)
Void OnWorkerStopped()  (0:0)
Void Dispose()  (0:0)
Void System.IDisposable.Dispose()  (0:0)
Void BaseWork(YellowPages.Contracts.IWorker, System.Threading.CancellationToken)  (0:0)
Void <Start>b__0()  (0:0)
Void InnerInvoke()  (0:0)
Void Execute()  (0:0)
Void ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)  (0:0)
Void RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)  (0:0)
Void Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)  (0:0)
Void ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)  (0:0)
Boolean ExecuteEntry(Boolean)  (0:0)
Void System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  (0:0)
Boolean Dispatch()  (0:0)
Boolean PerformWaitCallback()  (0:0))
```

Am I doing something wrong? What is the `PerformWaitCallback?` It seems like I'm preparing therad-pool-tasking bad.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something is causing the code inside `BaseWork` to terminate/finish execution. Are you catching any exceptions in your code?

Comment: What happens inside `worker.ProcessOnce`?

Comment: @kseen: Simply calling `new StackTrace().ToString()` would actually provide better insight instead of iterating through stack frames. Does the `while` loop also terminate? Or does it keep calling `worker.ProcessOnce()`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not in separate places, but one application-wide exception handler, I hope it catches any exceptions: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper`.

Comment: @Groo Thanks for the `StackTrace().ToString()`, I will place it alongside the iterating stack frames and will wait for result and then post it here. `While` should have finish, but at the moment it just invokes `ProcessOnce()` forever, but this moment isn't related to my issue.

Comment: @kseen: Did you try suggestions from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25262877/69809)?

Answer (score 1):

That whole stack trace part below `BaseWork` is simply the `Task` delegate being queued to the `ThreadPool`. If you simply wrote `Log.Instance.Info(new StackTrace().ToString())`, you would have gotten a bit more verbose listing, something like:

```
// this is the anonymous handler delegate where you print the stack trace
<BaseWork>b__3(System.Object, System.EventArgs)

// you worker fires the WorkerStopped inside the Dispose method
SomeClass.OnWorkerStopped()

// this is where your worker was diposed
YellowPages.Contracts.Worker.Dispose()

// this is when method was invoked
SomeClass.BaseWork(YellowPages.Contracts.IWorker, System.Threading.CancellationToken) 

// everything below this line is just your method being queued to the thread pool
// and is irrelevant
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext = {unknown}, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback = {unknown}, object state = {unknown}, bool preserveSyncCtx = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext = {unknown}, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback = {unknown}, object state = {unknown}, bool preserveSyncCtx = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Your actual problem is (most likely) that `worker.ProcessOnce()` throws an exception:

1. `worker.ProcessOnce()` throws an exception and it doesn't catch it.
2. The [`using` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) in `BaseWork` makes sure that `worker.Dispose()` is called, inside its implicit `finally` clause.
3. `worker.Dispose()` fires the `WorkerStopped` event which logs the stack trace.
4. Since there in no `catch` clause to catch the exception, it is silently swallowed by the `Task` (unless you're using .NET older than 4.5 or you have [the `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` option enabled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx)) .

If you called `Task.Wait()` somewhere, it would block the thread and then throw an `AggregateException` once the worker throws it. Since you're probably not waiting anywhere, you could create a continuation which will fire in case of an exception, i.e.:

```
_tasks.Add(Task.Factory

    // create the task
    .StartNew(() => BaseWork(currentWorker, _tokenSource.Token), _tokenSource.Token)

    // create the exception-only continuation
    .ContinueWith(t => 
          Log.Instance.Error(t.Exception.Flatten().ToString()),
          TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
);
```

Alternatively, you can simply add a `try/catch` block around the call to `worker.ProcessOnce()` and log the exception there (but the approach shown above will catch any exceptions thrown inside `BaseWork`, so it's safer to use it).

Adding this will allow you to log the actual exception. If it happened due to a bug in your code, fix it. Otherwise (if this is an exception which can be expected, like socket exceptions), add a `catch` handler for that exception and swallow it.

Also, it's not clear what the `ErrorOccurred` event is supposed to signal (probably not an exception)?

Answer (score 0):

simply surround `worker.ProcessOnce();` with a try catch block and make sure it's not throwing any exceptions.
if you find that's not the case, i am really suspecting that your logging system is crashing `Log.Instance.Info`. double check your logging class code and consider using locking in order to avoid simultaneous access to the same variable from multiple threads.

```
lock(myobject)
{
   .....
}
```